# react-bootstrap - issue with ie11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, react-bootstrap

I'm not able to get react-bootstrap to work with IE11. Here is what I did:

1. `create-react-app test-app`, then cd to `test-app` folder
2. `npm install --save bootstrap`
3. `npm install --save react-bootstrap`
4. `npm start`  (application opens in IE11 ok at this point)
5. Close browser and cancel the `npm start` operation
6. Edit `App.js` and add the following line at the top:

   - `import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';`
7. Run `npm start` again and open app in IE11. Browser screen is blank.

I checked the javascript Console but did not see any errors.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to install the react-app-polyfill and then add `import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';` to first line in src/index.js.  See [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-app-polyfill/README.md) for more details.

Many thanks to [mxschmitt](https://github.com/mxschmitt) on github for providing the [solution](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/3510#issuecomment-469245617).

Comment: most of us came to this point had got the ie to 'work'. but import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9' won't solve the react-bootstrap issue. contents are not in the right place. some of them may not display at all.

Comment: @Li Li - This solution worked well for me on IE11 when I used it 3 years ago.  But if you are still trying to support IE9 with the latest version of react (not sure what version you are using), that's a pretty tough goal to achieve. IE9 is absolutely ancient at this point.